# Windows Store App reading from text file

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing windows store app. I have this text file named: text.txt

```
account1 string1
account2 string2
account3 string3
```

And this c# code:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var path = "text.txt";
    var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    try
    {
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        test.Text = "error";
    }
}
```

Code can find text file without a problem. But i cannot read it. I want to read account names(account1, account2, account3) from text file, and add it into an arraylist named "x"
And add strings(string1, string2, string3) to arraylist named "y".

I would appreciate your helps. Regards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file into a string collection using [ReadLinesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readlinesasync%28v=win.10%29.aspx):

```
try
{
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
    var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // "line" variable should contain "account(x) string(x)"
        // You can then parse it here..
    }
}
...
```